# Android Studio Automatically Passing String on TextView from one activity to socket activity

Tags: java, sockets, android-studio

I found a tutorial on the internet that allows a client(android app) - server(java on netbeans) socket that allows me to send and recieve data/string on either side. The user will have to manually enter the data onto an EditText and then pressing the button send with an on click method.

> MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText e1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMessage);

    Thread myThread = new Thread(new MyServerThread());
    myThread.start();
}

class MyServerThread implements  Runnable{
    Socket s;
    ServerSocket ss;
    InputStreamReader isr;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    Handler h = new Handler();

    String message;
    @Override


    public void run() {

        try{
            ss = new ServerSocket(2222);
            while(true){
                s = ss.accept();
                isr = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                message = bufferedReader.readLine();

                h.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}


public void send(View v){
    MessageSender messageSender = new MessageSender();
    messageSender.execute(e1.getText().toString());

}


}
```

> MessageSender

```
public class MessageSender extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
Socket s;
DataOutputStream dos;
PrintWriter pw;
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {

    String message = voids[0];

    try{
        s = new Socket("192.168.254.105",2222);
        pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        pw.write(message);
        pw.close();
        s.close();

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Now what I am trying to do next is instead of manually typing into the GUI the text and pressing the send button, I want to to send a string on a TextView from another activity let's say Activity1.class to MainActivity.class using the following codes.(the show Textview conatains the text "Hello")

```
String message = show.getText().toString();
Intent intent= new Intent(Activity1.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("message_key", message);
startActivity(intent);
```

Ans will call it on the Main Activity with

```
String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message_key");
    passedMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPassed);
    passedMessage.setText(message);
```

Problem is after running the program, the passed string to textview on MainActivity will only display on the gui but will not send to the socket itself. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: All the code did that you posted was take a string from a TextView in Activity1 and paste it into a TextView in your MainActivity. After you call passedMessage.setText(message), you need to write the code that actually sends the string to the server! The reason why you're not sending the string to the server socket is because you never told it to do so!

Answer (score 0):

In the second activity you can:

```
String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message_key");
passedMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPassed);
if(message != null && !message.isEmpty()) {
    passedMessage.setText(message);
    sendButton.performClick();
}
```

And make sure to assign the ActionListener of the button before you call performClick